# WebStorm - how to see file's path in 'show usage' popup

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I do <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on some function or const, I can see a list of usages in a popup. But unfortunately I cannot see the whole path but only a filename. How can I set WebStorm so I can see the path too?

It is really annoying as many of files in my repo is called `index.ts` or `library.ts`. Without the path I can't choose the proper one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set WebStorm so I can see the path too?

Sadly you cannot.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-195508 -- watch this one and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified of any progress.

P.S. You can try "Find Usages" instead of "Show Usages". The later one shows results in this limited popup while the first one will display them in a more advanced toolwindow where grouping by file/folder is possible ([from my comment there](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-195508#focus=Comments-27-6623953.0-0)).

Comment: This issue has 5 years now... Seems like it won't be implemented any time... Really sad. 
Anyway - thanks for help!